# Solve an matrix trace equation: find x in Tr[(Y-xWY-FB)'(WY)]=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I have the following linear equation

$$   \mathrm{Tr}[(Y-xWY-FB)'(WY)]=0$$

where $Y$ is an $n$-by-$b$ matrix, $W$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix, $F$ is an $n$-by-$m$ matrix, $B$ is an $m$-by-$b$ matrix, and $x$ is an scalar. All $Y$, $W$, $F$ and $B$ matrices are known, but $x$ is unknown. Is there a close-form solution for $x$? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since the trace is linear, so you can easily isolate x:

$$ \eqalign {
 x*Tr[(WY)'(WY)] &= Tr[(Y-FB)'(WY)] \cr
 x &= \frac{Tr[(Y-FB)'(WY)] }{ Tr[(WY)'(WY)]} \cr 
} $$